# ASP.NET Web API 2 - double backslash in string after serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm dealing with issue of backslashes in the string.

I have method like this

```
public IHttpActionResult GetResult()
{
    return Ok(@"\");
}
```

But after JSON serialization I get this result in http response

> "\\"

Is there any possibility to disable adding backslash during serialization? I know that I can do it by replacing \\ with \ before response but it is not elegant way for me.

Comment: @ sign will make '\' to '\\'

Comment: yes but withut @ this Ok("\"); is not valid code

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - `"\\"` is a valid JSON string representing a single backslash. The result is the correct JSON representation of what you're asking for...

Comment: I wrote this example because of make it more simple. In the real scenario I need serialize google polyline string to output and double backslashes in response makes me some problems. Maybe deserializing could help me.

Comment: "make me some problems" is very unclear. Basically, you need to provide a more realistic example and describe the problem more thoroughly.

Comment: based on your code, the result is probably \. What tool do you use to see the response? The VS displays single \ as double \\ when inspecting strings which might confuse you.

Comment: @Dusan I use Chrome browser or Postman where I have double backslashes even when I choosed JSON->Pretty in Postman. In the Fiddler I have only one backslash so fiddler deserialize JSON correctly.

Comment: @JonSkeet my use case is quite complex to write. So I reduced my problem to most simple case. Basicly it is about when I coppied output with double backslashes and visualize google polyline in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility it showed me incorrect result. Problem was that displayed JSON in Postman was not deserialized correctly.

Comment: You reduced your problem to an *incorrect* case. It sounds like you probably didn't take into account that the tool doesn't accept JSON, it accepts text *without* the escaping that JSON requires...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't disable adding a backslash before a `\` because it wouldn't be valid JSON (see [here](http://www.json.org/)). The backaslash will always be added in the following cases:

[image]

But once your JSON is deserialized you should only get a single backslash for every `\\` in your JSON string.